# How do I customize and translate error messages in django's PasswordChangeForm?

Tags: django, django-authentication

[Change password error message shows only in english how to change it or translate it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jK7e.jpg)

/form/

```
class PasswordChangingForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    old_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type':'password'}))
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type':'password'}))
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type':'password'}))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('old_password','new_password1', 'new_password2')
```

---

/views.py/

```
class PasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):    
    form_class = PasswordChangingForm
    success_message = 'Амжилттай'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('settings_success')
```

---

/template/

```
<form method="POST">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        {% include '../extends/_messages.html' %}
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="st_pass1" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Нууц үг</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                {{ form.old_password }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="st_pass2" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Шинэ нууц үг</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                {{ form.new_password1 }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="st_pass3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Шинэ нууц үг
                                                давтах</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                {{ form.new_password2 }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div> 
                                        {{ form.errors}}
                                         <div class="text-center form-group pt-5" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary cs-btn">Хадгалах</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

(my first question in Stackoverflow. Please let me know if question unclear)

Comment: Since you write `success_message = 'Everything is fine'`, it will of course only display this in English.

Comment: i dont' know how to  edit quesiton but in picture(if you don't understand what they mean) 1st label = old_password, 2nd label= new_password, 3rd label = new_password_repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you write `success_message = 'Everything is fine'`, it will of course only display this in English.

The easiest way to make a translatable text is probably using [Django's translation API [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation). You can make this translatable with:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class PasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):    
    form_class = PasswordChangingForm
    success_message = _('Everything is fine')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('settings_success')
```

The same with the labels in the form:

```
class PasswordChangingForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    # …

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('old_password','new_password1', 'new_password2')
        labels = {
            'old_password': _('Old password'),
            'new_password1': _('New password'),
            'new_password2': _('Repeat new password'),
        }
```

Django already has a translation for [`'Old password'` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L370).

For the other ones, you can make translations with:

```
python3 manage.py makemessages -l de
```

where you change *`de`* to the iso code for which you want to make translations.

This will construct `.po` files where you can define the translations for the given strings. You can then use:

```
python3 manage.py compilemessages
```

to construct `.mo` files with the translations. For more information, see the [*translation* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translation).

Comment: Thank you so much old password(git-link) helped me lot. And one more question please, when i type "python3 manage.py makemessages -l mn"  it' not creating .po but showing "processing locale mn". And i did 'LOCALE_PATHS = [ BASE_DIR / 'locale']' in my settings.

Comment: @chuluunhvvNyamjaw: did you install `gettext` on your machine (since that is what is called by Django eventually).

Comment: yes i did from here https://github.com/mlocati/gettext-iconv-windows/releases , i use windows 10.

Comment: It's done after typing "django-admin.py makemessages -l mn" and deleting pycharm. Somehow when i type "django-admin.py ..." it's automatically call pycharm not running command fully. Thank you again.

Comment: @chuluunhvvNyamjaw: but exactly what happens? It prints the message and then errors, or waits for input or hangs, or something else?

Comment: when i tried "python manage.py makemessages -l mn" it shows [processing locale mn] but it didn't create .po file. and tried "django-admin makemessages -l mn"(without .py) i got same result. again  i tried "django-admin.py makemessages -a" it created .po file. So i tried "django-admin.py makemessages -l mn" this time but it always launch pycharm and says there's no "makemessages"(i use vs code)  so i deleted pycharm. After that "django-admin.py makemessages -l mn" after that it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

I need to add '_*init* _'to get the labels working on Django 4.1:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
class PasswordChangingForm(PasswordChangeForm):
# …
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['old_password', 'new_password1', 'new_password2']
    labels = {
        'old_password': _('Current password'),
        'new_password1': _('New password'),
        'new_password2': _('Repeat new password'),
    }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for key in self.Meta.labels: 
        self.fields[key].label = self.Meta.labels[key]
```